# how to pass a list of double quoted strings as an azure pipeline variable input to terraform task?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass a list of strings as an azure pipeline variable to a terraform task.

I have a variable created for the pipeline called such that `ips = [\"1.1.1.1\", \"2.2.2.2\"]` and I can access this in the azure pipeline using `$(ips)`

I want to pass this variable as mentioned [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line) in the official terraform documentation:
`terraform apply -var='image_id_list=["ami-abc123","ami-def456"]'` to the terraform plan task

here is my terraform plan section of the yaml:

```
        - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
          inputs:
            provider: 'azurerm'
            command: 'plan'
            commandOptions: '--var-file variables/$(Build.SourceBranchName)/$(Build.SourceBranchName).tfvars  -var=''allowips=$(ips)''' 
            environmentServiceNameAzureRM: $(linked_service)
          displayName: 'Terraform plan'
```

when the pipeline runs, it fails at the terraform plan step with the error -

```
terraform plan --var-file variables/dev/dev.tfvars -var='allowips=[ \1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ]'
stat \1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ]': no such file or directory
##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.12.28/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1
```

I have also tried various combinations of for declaring the azure pipeline variable like:
`ips = ["\"1.1.1.1\", \"2.2.2.2"\]`

which also gives the same error -

```
terraform plan --var-file variables/dev/dev.tfvars -var='allowips=[ "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ]'
stat "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ]': no such file or directory
##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.12.28/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried to a lot of combinations of setting quotes or double quotes on the `commandOptions` value and also the `ips` variable but I am getting the same errors (or valid terraforms error).

It seems the first double quote in the azure variable seems to causing some issues. Any pointers o how to pass a list of double quoted strings as an azure pipeline variable input to terraform task is much appreciated. Thanks!

edit -

I hardcoded the values directly in the yaml but still getting errors.

```
commandOptions: '--var-file variables/$(Build.SourceBranchName)/$(Build.SourceBranchName).tfvars -var=''allowips=[\"1.1.1.1\", \"2.2.2.2\"]'''
```

and it basically does not accept the ip values and asks for a manual entry:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.12.28/x64/terraform plan --var-file variables/dev/dev.tfvars -var='allowips=[\1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"]'
var.allowips
  Enter a value:
```

again it seems there is a problem around the first double quote.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you set the ips in your task directly instead of using variables?

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT i have added my observations as an edit in the original question

Comment: Unfortunately none of those links seems applicable to me... @Leo Liu-MSFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I dealt with a similar problem and [this answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6783#issuecomment-377070740) helped me a lot.

In a nutshell, you should define the variable `ips` as `["\"1.1.1.1\"", "\"2.2.2.2\""]`, and terraform plan task needs to take the variable as the following `-var=ips=$(ips)`.

Hope this helps anyone encountering a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> how to pass a list of double quoted strings as an azure pipeline variable input to terraform task?

I am afraid there is no such way to pass double quoted strings to terraform task at this moment.

That because the double quoted could not be escaped by the `\`.

You could check below threads for some more details:

- [Allow to add single quotes around double quotes string to be passed as tag values to AWS resources](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18358)
- [Output values are double quoted](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-k8s/issues/40)